# Formating a date in excel when combining text from multiple cells

Tags: excel, formatting

I have an excel sheet with some text in numerous cells and need to combine them into one cell. Easy, except one of the cells is a date and when combining the text you get the date in base number format and not in date format.

Example:

A1 = `"One"` 
A2 = `"Two"` 
A3 = `"05.12.2012"`
A4 = `=A1&" "&A2&" "&A3` = `"One Two 41248"`

Anyone know what I need to do before A3 in order for the formula to return 05.12.2012 instead of 41248. I have tried "DATE" and "DATEVALUE" etc.

If it is relevent, the date is derived from a formula which looks for a value in an array. I have left out this forumla for ease of reading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A4 = `=A1&" "&A2&" "&TEXT(A3,"DD.MM.YYYY")`

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Unfortunatley it does not quite work with my simple example. The day and month appear properly but the year is just YYYY. I have to use a semi-colom instead of a comma after the A3, but that should not make a difference. Any ideas why mine is still not working?

Comment: I found out my problem. I am using the Norwegian version of excel so I need to replace YYYY (year) with ÅÅÅÅ (år) and it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!  You can use any of the normal excel formatting options in the text function, e.g. `=TEXT(A3,"DDD DD MMM YY")` would result in `Mon 05 Dec 12`.