# TEXT function doesn't show months or year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

My =TEXT won't work. It doesn't show months or years. I have downloaded the [example template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) from the support page of Microsoft but I can't make it work. It does show days, which is weird. It doesn't matter which file or sheet I try, same result.

I have tried to change the number formats and reinstalled Excel, without progress. I don't know what is wrong.

[image: You can see the error here]

Comment: You might not want to answer but which country are you from ? Your national settings might be the problem.

Comment: F.e. my country uses r instead of y and we use comma as a decimal seperator instead of a point so I also can't use the example template that you linked.

Comment: I am from Sweden but are using the english version of Office.

Comment: I also got all Excel settings for English but I still have to use the dd.mm.rrrr format, do you know what's the equivalent of dd.mm.yyyy in Sweden ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the second comment in the answer to this question:

[Formating a date in excel when combining text from multiple cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723587/formating-a-date-in-excel-when-combining-text-from-multiple-cells)

I'm not sure about months, but try ÅÅÅÅ instead of YYYY. You can try hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+1, selecting "Custom" from "Category" in the "Number" tab. Scroll down until you get to starter codes for date formatting. That may show you what code is needed for `TEXT`.

You say you are using the English version, but your screenshot is showing torsdag instead of Saturday.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. For months I changed from mmmm to MMMM.